# How can I add custom meta tags using static metadata objects in next.js 13

Tags: javascript, next.js, metadata, next.js13

So I know that to block Pinterest on my site I need to embed this in my site's header `<meta name="pinterest" content="nopin" />`, but I'm not sure how to do that in Next 13 using the new exported metadata object format? Looked at the documentation for that object but couldn't figure it out.

```
export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};
```

EDIT (April 18th):
I'm not sure why it seemed to be working before, but adding the meta tag as suggested by Mathieu (and the documentation) doesn't seem to actually work.

I have this in my root layout file and pinterest pinning option still appears on my site

```
export const metadata = {
  other: { pinterest: "nopin" },
};
```

Answer (score 6):

to add custom metadata, you can use other category:

```js
export const metadata = {
  other: { pinterest: "nopin" },
};
```

next build will generate this metadata:

```html
<meta name="pinterest" content="nopin"/>
```

More information here: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/metadata#other

Comment: that definitely seems to b the correct answer according to the docs. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: My mistake, needed to hard refresh. It does work.

Comment: This does not solve the problem if you need to set the key as "property" instead of "name"

Comment: is there way to add class for meta tag? for example i need class="elastic"

Comment: Wow did it take me a long time to find this simple answer! This definitely works. Used it for adding the view-transition:same-origin meta tag, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem with snapchat creative kit.
NEXTjs `metadata` object doesn't allow adding arbitrary meta tags with `property` attribute (i.e. `<meta property='...' content='..' />`)

The solution that worked for me was adding the tag directly in the root layout.

```js
export default function RootLayout({ children }: Props) {
  return (
    <html>
      <meta
        property="snapchat:sticker"
        content="PATH-TO-STICKER"
      />
      <meta
        property="snapchat:app_id"
        content="APP-Id"
      />
      {children}
    </html>
  );
}
```

I believe this work for any layout or page and NEXT will merge your `<meta />` tag with what was generated by `metadata` API. The documentation mention this in [the unsupported meta tags](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#unsupported-metadata)

Answer (score -3):

it seems you just have to put your piece of code in your layout.js or page.js, like this :

```
export const metadata = {
  ...[Your previous meta data, like title, description,...]
  pinterest: "nopin"
};
```

Comment: Sadly, this is not working using nextjs13, other field must be used as explained here: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/metadata#other